# how to find line number for DOM elements in php?

Tags: php, dom

I want to check whether a `<img>` tag has `alt=""` text or not and also need to find what line   number in DOM that img tag is. At the moment I have the following codes written but stuck with finding the line number.
for example:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://www.google.com');
$htmlElement = $doc->getElementsByTagName('html');
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
echo $tags->item(0)->getLineNo();
foreach ($tags as $image) {
    // Get sizes of elements via width and height attributes
    $alt = $image->getAttribute('alt');
    if($alt == ""){
       $src = $image->getAttribute('src'); 
       echo "No alt text ";  
      echo '<img src="http://google.com/'.$src.'" alt=""/>'. '<br>';
    }
    else{
       $src = $image->getAttribute('src'); 
         echo '<img src="http://google.com/'.$src.'" alt=""/>'. '<br>';            
    }             
}
```

from the above code at the moment I am getting images and text saying that "no alt text" beside the image, but I want to get what line number that img tag appears.
for example here the line number is 57,

```
56. <div class="work_item">
57. <p class="pich"><img src="images/works/1.jpg"    alt=""></p>
58. </div>
```

Comment: Why do you need this? Perhaps there is a better way of going about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Oh, sorry for the flag, I misunderstood the question. Disregard the report mods.

Comment: hi asad, can you please explain what you mean. thanks

Comment: If you'll `echo` each line of HTML you can use the Magic constant: `__LINE__`

Comment: @alfasin The `__LINE__` magic constant is the current line number of code being interpreted, unless OP does a big long series of echo's I don't know if it will solve his problem :P

Comment: @DavidHarris right, that's what I said: "echo each line" ;)

Comment: i am trying to build an accessibility checker tool. user will enter url then ill produce everything from start to end of html tag including line numbers. then ill check for example if there is any alternative text missing for any image. if so then ill show the line number of that image tag that has alternative tag missing. hope it make sense. thanks

Comment: IMO that's a bad idea just to get a line number.

Comment: sorry the image will be there as well, i have added the code for that in my example.

Comment: Instead of parsing the entire DOM, why don't you just search for the string alt="" or use a regex to find alt-less <img> tags

Comment: Parse HTML with regexes? Heresy!

Comment: it's ok. figured out the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i have figured out what i was trying to achieve but not sure is that the right way. It is doing the job. Please leave comments or any other idea how can i improve it. 
If you go to the following site and type any URL. It will produce a report with accessibility issues in a webpage. It is an accessibility checker tool.

```
http://valet.webthing.com/page/
```

All i am trying to do is achieve that kind of layout. The code below will produce the DOM of supplied URL and find any image tag that does not have alternative text.

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php
    $dom = new domDocument;
// load the html into the object
    $dom->loadHTMLFile('$yourURLAddress');
// keep white space
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
// nicely format output
    $dom->formatOutput = true; 
    $new = htmlspecialchars($dom->saveHTML(), ENT_QUOTES);
    $lines = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $new); //split the string on new lines
    echo "<pre>";
    //find 'alt=""' and print the line number and html tag
    foreach ($lines as $lineNumber => $line) {

        if (strpos($line, htmlspecialchars('alt=""')) !== false) {
            echo "\r\n" . $lineNumber . ". " . $line;
        }
    }
    echo "\n\n\nBelow is the whole DOM\n\n\n";
    //print out the whole DOM including line numbers
    foreach ($lines as $lineNumber => $line) {
        echo "\r\n" . $lineNumber . ". " . $line;
    }
    echo "</pre>";
    ?>   
 </body> 
</html>
```

I like to thank everyone who helped specially "chwagssd" and Mike Johnson.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DOMNode::getLineNo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.getlineno.php#102771), e.g.`$line = $image->getLineNo()`.

Comment: sorry did not work. i used the codes i posted and URL was http://www.drumstudio.ie. i got 3 images and all of their line number is 0 which is not right.

Comment: i am trying different things but no joy yet :(

Answer (score 0):

HTML has no real concept of line numbers, since they are just whitespace.

With that in mind, you might be able to count how many newlines there are in all the text nodes preceding the target node. You might be able to do this with DOMXPath:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$node = /* your target node */;
$textnodes = $xpath->query("./preceding::*[contains(text(),'\n')]",$node);
$line = 1;
foreach($textnodes as $textnode) $line += substr_count($textnode->textContent,"\n");
// $line is now the line number of the node.
```

Please note that I have not tested this, nor have I ever used axes in xpath.